# selecting multiple ids by the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

$('.myclass').attr('id');

myclass is the class of the selected table cells which have unique ids. No more than 2 table cells can be selected at once by the user. I need to capture the ids of the selected table cells and assign them to var1 and var2. Users can deselect cells and choose new ones... I thought about using an array but that's probably not the best way.

Comment: Could you explain the problem better? I don't understand the whole "selected table cells" bit. How are cells "selected"? What does your current code look like?

Comment: @Phil
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.mytd').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('test1',!$this.hasClass('test1') &&  $('.test1').length < 2);
 $('.test1').attr('id');
})
})

This lets the user select 2 of 10 table cells. Cells can be deselected. Once they have selected the cells, they have to click the submit button. I then need to pull the ids of the two selected classes and post them with the form. I think I can use the code you provided when the submit button is clicked and pull the values and assign them to hidden inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with the array option using [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), eg

```
var ids = $('.myclass').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();

if (ids.length >= 2) {
     var var1 = ids[0];
     var var2 = ids[1];
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to pull all of the values with an array? The user can select ids 1 and 2 and then deselect them and select 3 and 4. I would have all of the values in the array. How would I know which ones are the final two the user selected and submitted?

Comment: could you please tell me why do you use `.get()` in the end there? Isn't `get` for retrieving DOM elements from jQuery collection? Looking into [docs](http://api.jquery.com/get/) I can only find “Without a parameter, .get() returns all of the elements”, but that is about DOM elements isn't it?

Comment: @gryzzly The `get()` in my answer returns the matched array. Without it, I would have a jQuery object.

Comment: @Phil Never mind I guess I could run the function once the final two have selected. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, just followed the source here: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.get and found out it just turns the $ object into real array. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

```
var selectedCells = []; 

$('.myclass').each(function() { selectedCells.push($(this).attr('id')) });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array and assign it to var1 and var 2 depending upon size.

```
arr = $.map($('.myclass'), function (element) { 
  return element.id; 
});
```